# Не работает стартовая строка в боте

Tags: python, telebot

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Мне нужно получать  user.id или chat.id чтобы отдельным людям присылать сообщения но нужная переменная выделяется KeyEror
вот текст ошибки

```
File "C:\Users\пк\Desktop\BOT 2.0\bas.py", line 103, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)

  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1044, in polling
    logger_level=logger_level, allowed_updates=allowed_updates)
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1118, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1074, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 156, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 100, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 6308, in _run_middlewares_and_handler
    result = handler['function'](message)
  File "C:\Users\пк\Desktop\BOT 2.0\bas.py", line 35, in start
    bot.send_message(config.myId, text='@{0.username} его id {asd}'.format(message.from_user, reply_markup=markup))
KeyError: 'asd'
```

```
def start(message):
    asd = (message.chat.id)
    sti = open('static\welcome.webp', 'rb')
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, sti)
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Хочу получить 100 рублей")
    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("❓ Задать вопрос")
    btn3 = types.KeyboardButton('Магазин')
    markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Привет, {0.first_name}! я бот который может тебе помочь!".format(message.from_user), reply_markup=markup)
    #bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='{0.username}'.format(message.from_user, reply_markup=markup))
    bot.send_message(config.myId, text='@{0.username} по имени {0.first_name} открыл бота'.format(message.from_user, reply_markup=markup))
    bot.send_message(config.myId, text='@{0.username} его id {asd}'.format(message.from_user, reply_markup=markup))[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]
```

Comment: Чтобы вам было проще помочь, выложите ошибку текстом.

Comment: пару секунд.....

Comment: `format` не понимает, откуда ему брать `{asd}`.

Comment: так там-же указана то что ``` asd = (message.chat.id) ```

Comment: @AndreYoug `format` так не умеет. Если хотите взять из переменной значение, то используйте `f-строку`, это не тоже самое, что `format`.

Comment: У вас там кстати и скобка много где неправильно стоит. `reply_markup=markup` у вас попадает внутрь `format`, а это неправильно